# Hardware access using Flash

Tags: flash

Is it possible to access Hardware service routine using flash?

Answer (score 0):

nope - aside from building something targeting flash 10 which uses HwA - you cannot use anything underneath the API - that is AS3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with AIR and the [Native Process API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process_02.html).